# Syntax for a User Input 2D Array within a Nested Struct?

Tags: c

**The problem:**

- **Create a nested structure to store coordinates of end points of a
  line segment.**
- **In a program, prompt the user for the coordinates and
  print them.**

I was able to create the code and get it working, as can be seen below, but I had to do so by filling in the values for an array beforehand, then having the user's input replace these pre-assigned values. My intuition is that there is a better way of doing this (e.g., by declaring an empty array to begin with), and I'd like to know how.

Though I was able to get the code working by using:
        `lineseg myline = {{4,2},{5,9}};`, this is not what I want.

I made a number of attempts at creating an empty array, but none worked.

e.g., by trying `lineseg myline[2][2];` instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x,
        y;
} point;

typedef struct
{
    point pt1,
          pt2;
} lineseg;

void main()
{
    lineseg myline = {{4,2},{5,9}};

    printf("Enter x coordinate for the first point: ");
    scanf("%d",&myline.pt1.x);
    printf("Enter y coordinate for the first point: ");
    scanf("%d",&myline.pt1.y);
    printf("Enter x coordinate for the second point: ");
    scanf("%d",&myline.pt2.x);
    printf("Enter y coordinate for the second point: ");
    scanf("%d",&myline.pt2.y);
    printf("\nPoint 1: (%d,%d)  Point 2: (%d,%d)",myline.pt1.x,
           myline.pt1.y,myline.pt2.x,myline.pt2.y);
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter 3 ,1, 4, and 8, the output statement correctly prints "Point 1: (3,1)  Point 2: (4,8)"

Any suggestions on how to do so without writing over a declared array would be terrific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to initialize `myline` with any values. You just need to declare it.

```
lineseg myline;
```